# How to find value of input field using name attribute?

Tags: javascript, dhtml

How to access the value of this input field by its name attribute using Javascript

```
<input type='text' name='hey'>

document.querySelectorAll('input[name=hey]').value;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You were close, As [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a list so you can use indexer to access the elements.

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[name=hey]')[0].value
```

better use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
document.querySelector('input[name=hey]').value
```

If your input name itself includes square brackets e.g. `hey[]`, you would enclose the name in double quotes:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="hey[]"]').value
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are flexible to use JQuery the here is the answer.

```
    $("input[name=hey]").val();
```

Using Javascript, you can access it like this:-

```
    document.getElementsByName('key')[0].value;
```

Look into this jsfiddle:-

https://jsfiddle.net/pLmvrdf3/

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
document.getElementsByName(name)
```

Since you wanted javascript? Or do you want JQuery?
cheers!

Comment: this is correct.but this returns an array.so you have to use 'document.getElementsByName(name)[0].value' in order to get the value